# Thonny how to fix this stacked label

Tags: python, tkinter, thonny

When I press OK to print out the answer multiple times, the answers just stack on each other but are not replaced by each other, how do I fix this bug?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
def main():
    global window
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    window.geometry("540x540")

    label1 = Label(window, text="Calculator", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    label1.pack()

    global entry1
    entry1 = Entry(window, width=20, font=("Arial 20"))
    entry1.pack()
    entry1.focus()

    label2 = Label(window, text="+", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    label2.pack()

    global entry2
    entry2 = Entry(window, width=20, font=("Arial 20"))
    entry2.pack()
    entry2.focus()

    global label3
    label3 = Label(window, text="=", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    label3.pack()

    button2 = Button(window, text="OK", fg="blue",
                 font="Arial 16 bold", command =button2_click)
    button2.pack()

    window.mainloop()


def button2_click():
    Label.after(0, label.master.destroy)
    try:
        a = int(entry1.get())
        b = int(entry2.get())
        Label(window, text=f"{a+b}", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue").pack()  
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Invalid Entry or Entry Missing!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The line `Label.after(0, labal.master.destroy)` will raise exception.  `Label.after(...)` is not correct, it should be something like `window.after(...)`. Note also that `label` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to create the result label once inside `main()` and update its text inside `button2_click()`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def main():
    global entry1, entry2, result

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    window.geometry("540x540")

    label1 = Label(window, text="Calculator", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    label1.pack()

    entry1 = Entry(window, width=20, font=("Arial 20"))
    entry1.pack()
    entry1.focus()

    label2 = Label(window, text="+", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    label2.pack()

    entry2 = Entry(window, width=20, font=("Arial 20"))
    entry2.pack()

    label3 = Label(window, text="=", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    label3.pack()

    # create result label
    result = Label(window, font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
    result.pack()

    button2 = Button(window, text="OK", fg="blue", font="Arial 16 bold", command=button2_click)
    button2.pack()

    window.mainloop()


def button2_click():
    # below line will raise exception
    #Label.after(0, label.master.destroy)
    try:
        a = int(entry1.get())
        b = int(entry2.get())
        # update result label
        result.config(text=f"{a+b}")
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Invalid Entry or Entry Missing!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I moved the `button2_click ()` to the top. I comment out in line 17.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


window = Tk()
window = Tk()
def main():
    global window
     
    window.title("Calculator")
    window.geometry("540x540")
    
label1 = Label(window, text="Calculator", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
label1.pack()

def button2_click():
    Label.after(0, label.master.destroy)
    try:
        a = int(entry1.get())
        b = int(entry2.get())
        Label(window, text=f"{a+b}", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue").pack()  
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Invalid Entry or Entry Missing!")

global entry1
entry1 = Entry(window, width=20, font=("Arial 20"))
entry1.pack(ipadx =10, ipady= 10)
entry1.focus()

label2 = Label(window, text="+", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
label2.pack()

global entry2
entry2 = Entry(window, width=20, font=("Arial 20"))
entry2.pack()
entry2.focus()

global label3
label3 = Label(window, text="=", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue")
label3.pack(ipadx =20, ipady= 20)

button2 = Button(window, text="OK", fg="blue",
             font="Arial 16 bold", command =button2_click)
button2.pack()

window.mainloop()


def button2_click():
    Label.after(0, label.master.destroy)
    try:
        a = int(entry1.get())
        b = int(entry2.get())
        Label(window, text=f"{a+b}", font=("Windsor", 30), fg="light blue").pack()  
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Invalid Entry or Entry Missing!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```